# How to get from heat equation with final condition to one with initial condition?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

How do I get from the heat equation with end condition
$$\frac{d}{dt}u(x,t) + \Delta u(x,t) = f(x,t)$$
$$u(x,T) = u_0(x)$$
where $t \in (0,T)$ and $x \in \Omega$, to a normal heat equation with initial condition?

if I substitute $s= T-t$, I dont know how to treat the time derivative.

Comment: Isn't the heat equation in backward time an ill-posed problem?

Comment: @RonGordon Maybe not if $u_0$ is smooth.

Comment: Only Stephen Hawking ever had the temerity to suggest that the time arrow might eventually go backwards. Fortunately he corrected himself.

Comment: @T.A.E. But see this http://www.dmmm.uniroma1.it/pubblicazioni/doc/phd_quaderni/02-1-and.pdf. The equations (4.7) and (4.8) is backwards (page 28).

Comment: Sorry i got the sign of Laplacian wrong, maybe it makes a difference? @RonGordon and T.A.E

Comment: Yes, it makes a difference. Good that you caught that.

Comment: By the way, the heat equation is $\frac{d}{dt}h-C\nabla h=...$ where $C > 0$. The equation you have stated is not the heat equation.

Comment: This is like a kolmogorov backward equation. It needs a terminal condition to be well posed. But you could make the substitution suggested below and you'll get a heat equation with an initial condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pose $\tau=T-t$ you have:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}=\frac{\partial}{\partial (T-t)}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t},
$$
then everything should flow.